# React Redux action creator dipatched twice on one call

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch

the following code works perfectly:

```
const onMenuItemClick = (item) => {
return {
    type: "MENU_ITEM_CLICKED"
}
```

this code dispatches the action twice:

```
const onMenuItemClick = (item) => {
document.getElementById("menu-button").click();
return {
    type: "MENU_ITEM_CLICKED"
}
```

my question is, why does this click makes the action dispatches twice?

Comment: That looks like it could cause an infinite loop of dispatches.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: i have a sidemenu that needs to close on a click at a menuitem. Normally the menu button open and closes the menu and the toggle variable is within a containers state that is not accessible by the menu items, also i cannot move the toggle to the global state. any ideas @nbkhope ?  kjprice: it is exactly dispatched twice, and only this action. it doesnt seems to be a loop or a infinite loop.

Comment: If you need something else to close, you dispatch a second action that closes it. You don't programmatically trigger a click event.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has a similar problem, here is how i fixed it:

i have rewritten the application a little bit, the toggle variable is now not in the local state anymore, i have put it now on the global redux state and i can share it between multiple components.

beginner problem i guess :)